# Using Mozilla Personal Verifier

Tags: javascript, mozilla, persona

I am doing a front-end heavy web app which does *Facebook login already with **pure Javascript**.*

Now I wan to include Mozilla Persona, I tried to use this URL as verifier:

https://verifier.login.persona.org/verify

But browser is complaining that there is No `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.`

I understand that if I make my verifier and make it CORS-enabled then this will be fixed, but my question is can we use the URL above for doing pure Javascript Persona verification?